# Synchronization over primitive inetger value in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, primitive

I have two java threads. One of them prints even numbers, and other prints odd numbers. I need to print the numbers in their natural order. Is it possible to synchronize both threads to only using primitive integer as shown below?
Node : primitive assignment are atomic in java across jvm.

```
public class NaturalNumber{

volatile   int  ai = 0;
public static void main(String str[]){
    final NaturalNumber nn = new NaturalNumber();

        Thread even = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        int i=0;
            public void run(){
                //int i=0;
                while(i<=200){
                    if(nn.ai ==0){
                        System.out.println(i);
                        i=i+2;
                        nn.ai =1 ;

                    }
                }
            }
        }); 

        Thread odd = new Thread( new Runnable(){
            int i=1;
            public void run(){
                //int i=1;
                while(i<=200){
                    if(nn.ai ==1) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        i=i+2;
                        nn.ai =0 ;
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        odd.start();
        even.start();


}
```

}

Comment: I get the desired output when I run the code.

Comment: To prevent perpetual looping, you need to do **something** that establishes a happens-before relationship between a write to `nn.ai` in one thread and a read of it in the other thread. As it is, `odd` could be sitting with `nn.ai` 0 in its cache, and `even` with it 1, and neither make any progress.

Comment: While this seems to work, I think it would be safer to implement a scheme similar to producer/consumer, where one of the two threads blocks until the other has printed out its next value.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to implement it using locking and synchronization, which I think is less error prone.

```
public class NaturalNumber{

private boolean printEven = true;
private Object lock = new Object();

public NaturalNumber()
{
    new Thread(()->even()).start();
    new Thread(()->odd()).start();
}

private void even()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i<=200)
    {
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            if(printEven)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                i += 2;
                lock.notify();
                printEven = false;
            }
            else //flag says next odd is to be printed, so wait until it has
            {
                try
                {
                    lock.wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private void odd()
{
    int i = 1;
    while(i<=200)
    {
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            if(!printEven)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                i += 2;
                lock.notify();
                printEven = true;
            }
            else //flag says next even is to be printed, so wait until it has
            {
                try
                {
                    lock.wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String str[]){

    new NaturalNumber();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, it not only keep keeps access to the printing and evaluating code synchronized, but prevents the same thread to get the lock twice (by doing nothing).

```
class NaturalNumber
{
private static boolean nextIsOdd = false;
public static void main(String str[])
{
   Thread even = new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
       public void run() {
          int i = 0;
          while(i<=200) {
             synchronized(this) {
                if(!nextIsOdd) {
                   System.out.println(i);
                   i=i+2;
                   nextIsOdd = true;
                }
             }
          }
        }
     }); 

   Thread odd = new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
       public void run() {
          int i = 1;
          while(i<=200) {
             synchronized(this) {
                if(nextIsOdd) {
                   System.out.println(i);
                   i=i+2;
                   nextIsOdd = false;
                }
             }
          }
        }
     }); 

    odd.start();
    even.start();
}
}
```

In any case, to avoid possible collisions a more elegant answer is to use [locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) and lock from one thread, unlock from the other.